# How to animate mapView annotations from one location to another?

Tags: ios, animation, dictionary

I have a situation in my iPhone app where I should move my annotations (car image) from one location to another location....I am quite new to iOS. I am getting coordinates from server in particular time manner. I have already used `HGMovingAnnotationSample` but my condition is different.
Please help me. I already wasted too much time on it.

Comment: You are using apple maps or google maps?

Comment: i am using apple maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you used simple animation using

```
-(void) animateAnnotation:(MyAnnotation*)annotation{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f
                    animations:^{
                         annotation.coordinate = newCordinates;
                    }
                    completion:nil];
}
```

Just check it out may be it will help you.

Comment: hai is there  any option similar function for google map?

Comment: Hi, i am having a problem. `annotation.coordinate` is a read only property.

Comment: @iHulk this works great for Apple maps. How do would you do this with Google maps?