# How can I animate pin movement in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm making a location-based game in Swift where the user views a map, several pins need to pop up at random spots near the edges of the view and then start moving toward the user's location. Is this possible? What method would I even look into to do this? The closest thing I can seem to find has to do with simulating routes, but that seems needlessly complex when I don't need the pins to navigate around buildings or anything, just go directly to the user's location.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [Animate MapKit annotation coordinate change in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776549/animate-mapkit-annotation-coordinate-change-in-swift), and it's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29776550/2803660).

Also [How to animate mapView annotations from one location to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015904/how-to-animate-mapview-annotations-from-one-location-to-another)

They're basically changing the annotation's location in a `UIView.animateWithDuration:` block.